# How to find some specific nodes/elements in a list?

Tags: prolog

I have a list in this form:

```
[node(2,5,4,3),node(3,5,4,3),node(2,10,12,4),node(5,2,2,2)]
```

I need a method that returns all the nodes that have the first value of 2.
Then:

```
[node(2,5,4,3),node(2,10,12,4)]
```

I tried different methods but without success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your attempt with `findall`?

Comment: `trovaNodiConUgualeS(S, [nodo(F,S,A,G)|_], nodo(F,S,A,G)):-!.

trovaNodiConUgualeS(S, [nodo(B,X,L,E)|Tail], Res):-

    S \= X,

    trovaNodiConUgualeS(S,Tail,Res).`
 I tried this, but "Arguments are not suficiently instatiated".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
| ?- findall(
       node(2,X,Y,Z),
       member(node(2,X,Y,Z),[node(2,5,4,3),node(3,5,4,3),node(2,10,12,4),node(5,2,2,2)]),
       Nodes).

Nodes = [node(2,5,4,3),node(2,10,12,4)]

yes
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make a check of the pattern we are looking for:

```
nodetwo(node(2, _, _, _)).
```

Then we can use [**`include/3`** <sup>[swi-doc]</sup>](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3) to filter the list:

```
?- include(nodetwo, [node(2,5,4,3),node(3,5,4,3),node(2,10,12,4),node(5,2,2,2)], L).
L = [node(2, 5, 4, 3), node(2, 10, 12, 4)].
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid taking the value from the knowledge base? Then somthing like this: `?- include(node(2,X,Y,Z), [node(2,5,4,3),node(3,5,4,3),node(2,10,12,4),node(5,2,2,2)], L).`